# Backbone Router on any page change event

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have the following routes:

```
routes: {
    ''                              : 'showSchedulePage',
    'Assignment/:assignmentTitle'   : 'showAssignment',
    ':pageType/:pageName'           : 'showPage'
},
```

Instead of the same code being fired in each of these functions, how can I fire a function when the URL is ANY one of the ones up top?

Thanks!

Comment: I hope I understand this correctly. You have some code, which has to be  copied / called in all of "showSchedulePage", "showAssingment", "showPage" and you would like to put this code out of these functions. If that is case, you can try to check: https://github.com/boazsender/backbone.routefilter

Comment: I think this will be the solution ;)

Comment: Yes this is what I was looking for!! Thanks drax. Add it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backbone plugin [Routefilter](https://github.com/boazsender/backbone.routefilter) allows you to define actions, which should be invoked before and after any route is executed. This allows you to extract common code from route handlers.

Comment: Perfect plugin. A must-have for more complex apps.