# BackboneJS - Navigation and display issue

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-routing

I have setup a main navigation menu with 4-5 anchors and the related views. Its the typical "home", "about", "news" etc menu. In one of the views, lets say "news" there is an additional menu with 3 anchors, lets say "national", "international" and "others", when you click those, it displays the related view inside the "news" view and its only supposed to be displayed there. So far so good. But then, when i click on "about" anchor on the main navigation, it shows me the about view, but also still the additional menu from the "news" view and of course I don't want that. So, what to do here?

**[UPDATE]**: I made some changes, but still it does not work!

I added backbone.view-prototype code into my mainpage.js:

```
define(function (require) {

'use strict';

Backbone.View.prototype.close = function(){
    this.remove();
    this.unbind();
    if (this.onClose){
        this.onClose();
    }
}

var AppRouter = require('../app/routers/router');

$(function () {

    var App = new AppRouter();

});

});
```

and i added the close function into my view:

```
define(['backbone','handlebars', 'text!templates/News.html'],



    function(Backbone,Handlebars, Template) {

        'use strict';


        var NewsView = Backbone.View.extend({

            template: Handlebars.compile(Template),

            events: {
            },

            initialize: function () {
                _.bindAll(this);
            },

            render: function() {
                $(this.el).html(this.template());
                return this;
            },

            close: function(){
                this.remove();
                this.unbind();
            }

        });

        return NewsView;    

    }
 );
```

My router looks like this (short version):

```
        var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

        routes: {
            '': 'index',
            'pages/about' : 'about',
            'pages/news' : 'news',
            'pages/news/national' : 'national',
            'pages/news/international' : 'international',
            'pages/news/other' : 'other',
            'pages/contact' : 'contact'
        },

        //Initializing the application
        initialize: function () {
            var self = this;

            //Collections
            this.mainMenuCollection = new MainMenuCollection();
            this.newsMenuCollection = new NewsMenuCollection();

            //Views
            this.mainMenuView = new MainMenuView({el:'#mainMenu', collection:this.mainMenuCollection});

            this.mainMenuCollection.fetch({success: function(collection) {
                self.mainMenuView.collection=collection;
                self.mainMenuView.render();
            }});

            this.newsMenuCollection.fetch({success: function(newscollection) {
                self.newsMenuView.newscollection=newscollection;
                self.newsMenuView.render();
            }});

            Backbone.history.start({
                pushState: false
            });

        },

        //Default route.
        index: function () {
            var self = this;
        },

        about: function() {
            this.aboutView = new AboutView({el:'#topContent'}).render();
        },

        news: function() {
            this.newsView = new NewsView({el:'#topContent'}).render();
            this.subMenuView = new SubMenuView({el:'#subMenu', collection:this.subMenuCollection}).render();
        },


        about: function() {
            this.aboutView = new AboutView({el:'#topContent'}).render();
        },

        contact: function() {
            this.contactView = new ContactView({el:'#topContent'}).render();
        },

        national: function() {
            this.nationalView = new NationalView({el:'#subContent_2'}).render();
        },

        international: function() {
            this.internationalView = new InternationalView({el:'#subContent_2'}).render();
        },

        other: function() {
            this.otherView = new OtherView({el:'#subContent_2'}).render();
        }                       


    });

    return Router;
}
```

Comment: The problem you describe is too broad to tell what it is just from your router. Try replicating the problem in a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/, then edit your question and paste the link.

Comment: isnt there some "onchange" function?

Comment: No there is no on change function, you have to manually call a function on every route if you want to do something like that. If you did do that though, you could manually empty the DOM elements that need to be cleared each time, then you may solve your problem with previous views still being visible.

Comment: ok, any example i can relate to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok lets simplify what you are trying to achieve:

- Go to 'News' route, add additional menu
- Move away from 'News' route, remove the news sub-menu

Now in vanilla Backbone, the only way to do is to do it manually. Something like this:

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({       

        onBeforeRoute: function () {
            if (this.subMenuView) this.subMenuView.$el.empty();

            // anything else you need to do
        },

        ...

        //Default route.
        index: function () {
            this.onBeforeRoute();

            var self = this;
        },

        about: function() {
            this.onBeforeRoute();           

            this.aboutView = new AboutView({el:'#topContent'}).render();
        },

        news: function() {
            this.onBeforeRoute();

            this.newsView = new NewsView({el:'#topContent'}).render();
            this.subMenuView = new SubMenuView({el:'#subMenu', collection:this.subMenuCollection}).render();
        },

        ...
}
```

Check out [the docs here](http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove) to see about the remove method.

One other thing I would suggest, is instantiating your views in your initialize method. If you keep recreating them every time a route is fired, the old views hang around in memory and are still bound to the DOM, causing strange issues if your views are bound to data etc. I can see you have something happening to stop this in the `close` method you have implemented, but it looks like you're not actually calling it anywhere.

Also, I would say it is frustrating when you first try to get to grips with Backbone, but stick with it, and keep reading articles on best practices etc, cause you always need to remember that Backbone IS NOT A FRAMEWORK! It is a very simple library, it offers nothing really in the way of conventions or ways to structure your application (which is why many people like it). I love Backbone but I actually use it along with [Marionette](http://marionettejs.com), which provides a lot of nice ways to structure your application. I recommend checking it out.

Comment: Also I just read your comments on the other answer that mention your close method. Just to clarify, that close method is only concerned with making sure that any DOM events linking the view to the DOM are removed, to stop the 'Zombie View' behaviour I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: But this will completely remove the views, so if I click on "about" the submenu and content is gone like it should but when I click on "news" again, the submenu and its content is not available anymore at all...

Comment: Ah ok so the `remove()` method is getting rid of the `#subMenu` element so when you go back the render doesn't work? If that's the case try changing the `remove` call to `view.$el.empty()`, see my edit.

Comment: Awesome! `view.$el.empty()` did it! great, thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

this looks like similar issue to this: [Backbone Router on any page change event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20132549/backbone-router-on-any-page-change-event/20187150#20187150)

You can use [Routefilter](https://github.com/boazsender/backbone.routefilter) plugin, and define *before* function, which can cleanup views, that should no longer be visible.

Comment: what about backbone.View.protype.close= function(){        this.remove();this.unbind();} ?

Comment: hmm..maybe I didn't understand the question correctly. I assumed, you are looking for some way to call cleanup code (close views, remove html,..) before router method is invoked.

Comment: well, maybe you are right and I just dont get this shit :-) Like I wrote in my question, when I go to a different view/page, the previous view is still visible, and I dont want that